# Say I didn't like the syntax of objC blocks... (or: how to customize llvm a little bit)

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction, llvm

...is there anything I could do about it?

To be more precise, I would like to replace the caret "^" with something like "§" - granted, there's not much left on the keyboard that's not in use already.

After thinking about it for a while (dismissed using run script build phases along the way) I think the only way to do it would be a custom llvm build.

While I don't quite think I'm ready to deal with the internals of compilers, I have the naive hope that replacing one symbol with another isn't too hard. And the idea of building and running my own version of a compiler tickles me, be it just for a good deal of childish fun.

So I started poking around in the llvm sources, but - surprise - got nowhere so far.

If someone is familiar with these kind of things, could you please point me to a place to look at?

That would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Extending LLVM can be a bit of a hassle, especially considering how fast-moving the compiler team is, so it's a good thing you don't have to. The C preprocessor exists to perform the exact same thing you've outlined (text replacement). I'm fairly sure § isn't aliased to anything important, so `#define § ^` should work great.  If you still want to write your own module, LLVM [provides instructions](http://llvm.org/docs/ExtendingLLVM.html) on how to extend their compiler.

Comment: There may be issues with tossing a non-ASCII character into the works, but at least it is 8 bit.

Comment: To my knowledge, preprocessor macros require the macro names to consist of letters, numbers and underscores only (first character must always be a letter). And indeed, if I try #define BLOCK ^ it works as expected, but it won't allow §. Is there a way around that, too? Edit: Oh and thanks for the link, I'll take a look at it. Doesn't really matter if I succeed in the end, I'm here to learn...

Comment: I don't think CLANG is very well suited to extended character sets, but I know GCC can handle it.  Try switching compilers (to LLVM-GCC)

Comment: That would mean giving up ARC... Not quite what I was looking for :) But never mind, I'll dig into the matter and take a closer look at the link you provided these days. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Toastor No problem.  At least you're going into it with the right attitude!

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code relevant for such a change isn't a part of LLVM at all, but a part of its Objective-C frontend, called Clang. Confusingly, "Clang" is also the name of the entire C/C++/ObjC compiler based on both Clang and LLVM.

> While I don't quite think I'm ready to deal with the internals of compilers, I have the naive hope that replacing one symbol with another isn't too hard.

And you'll be right. What you're trying to do is very simple change.

In fact, if `^` was *only* used for blocks, it would be a trivial change - just modify the lexer to generate the "caret" token from `§` instead of `^`: [take a look at the lexer code](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Lex/Lexer.cpp) to see what I mean (search for ^).

Unfortunately it's used for xor as well, so we'll have to modify both the lexer and the parser. The lexer to [add a new token type](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/TokenKinds.def) and [create that token from `§`](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Lex/Lexer.cpp), [the parser](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Parse/ParseExpr.cpp) to actually do something with it, e.g. by adding:

```
case tok::section:  // 'section' is the token type you've added
  Res = ParseBlockLiteralExpression();
  break;
```

(and then fixing the `assert` at the beginning of `ParseBlockLiteralExpression()`).

You might run into some issues, though, as § isn't in ASCII - though as far as I know Clang should be able to deal with UTF-8 encoded files.

Comment: That looks very promising! I'll definitely give it a try and will keep you posted on the results! Thanks in advance!!